# Literate programming: tool to extract and run a script from source in one pass?

Tags: shell, extract, execute, literate-programming

I just started reading about literate programming and [`noweb`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noweb) - and I find it quite interesting. As far as I understand it, the '`notangle`' step is the one that extracts (machine) source code (file), from the literal programming (source) file.

Here, I'm interested in one specific aspect: I would like to be able to extract multiple source files in one pass (in the `notangle` step) , *including an execution script* - and run the execution script in the same step!

An example in bash would look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# file: test.c.gdb.sh 

# generate C source file
cat > test.c <<"EOF"
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) {
  return 0;
}
EOF

# generate gdb script file
cat > test.gdb <<"EOF"
break main
run
EOF

# run the 'execution script'

gcc -g -Wall test.c -o test.exe
chmod +x test.exe
gdb -x test.gdb -se test.exe
```

The point in this, is that I can just call '`./test.c.gdb.sh`' from the shell, and I'll have the source files generated, then compiled, and then have the debugger started automatically.

Is there a literate programming tool, that would allow something like this in the `notangle` step?

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> extract multiple source files in one pass (in the notangle step), including an execution script - and run the execution script in the same step!

Folks sometimes use make, ant, scons or maven for this kind of thing.

A "single" magical command can't cover very many bases very well.  So it's left to external tools to do this.

Often, the final report or document requires complex, multi-step processing through various LaTeX tools.  This, too, may require a simple build script or tool setup.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @S.Lott - good to have the references on make, ant, scons or maven (haven't heard about maven before); good to have it confirmed that in this case, it's up to external tools. Cheers!

Comment: @sdaau: Literate programming is not about magical tools to magically make programming "easier" or "simpler".  The tools, actually, are usually **more** complex than illiterate programming.  After all, programming is hard to begin with.  Literate program merely exposes how inherently difficult it is.